# CRAN : how often can i push updates?

Tags: r, cran

I've pushed recently my first package to CRAN, [there](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cort/index.html). Is seems from the cran checking results [there](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_cort.html) and from other continuous integration tools that everything is ok regarding `r cmd check`. However, continuing developpement of the package myself, i found some bugs that are now corrected on github.

I undertand that cran people are volunteers, but i wander : [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html), they say :

> Submitting updates should be done responsibly and with respect for the volunteers’ time. Once a package is established (which may take several rounds), “no more than every 1–2 months” seems appropriate.

What do they mean by *once a package is established* ? Should i correct the bugs i found right now or wait a month ? The bugs are not critical (the package installs fine and do work properly) but foundamental (some parts are just wrong).

Thanks for any advice

Comment: If you send the update now, are you reasonably sure you won't need another update for a month or two?  If the answer is no, then I'd say you should wait.  (I don't understand the comment that it "works properly" but is "just wrong".   That might suggest updating now.)  Use your judgment, or ask them if you aren't sure.

Comment: By this comment i meant that the code works (doesnt give any error, warnings, message), but doesnt give the right answers. Thanks for the heuristic about the chance of re-updating in th next months, i'll keep to that and wait a litle more.